# Memcache/Membase configuration failing with "Failed to initialize the pool. - System.FormatException: An invalid IP address was specified'

Tags: memcached, membase

I have membase server setup, and am successfully using a memcache bucket, but I can't get a membase bucket to work.

My config is simple

```
<membase>
<servers bucket="membase" retryCount="3">
  <add uri="http://192.168.1.250:8091/pools/default" />
</servers>
```

Same setup is working fine with memcache running off the membase server.

I'm not sure about the pools/default bit, as there's no mention of that in the membase gui, but all the docs say to use it.

The full diagnostics log is

```
2012-01-05 11:49:06 [ERROR] 6 Membase.MembasePool - Failed to initialize the pool. -   System.FormatException: An invalid IP address was specified.
   at System.Net.IPAddress.InternalParse(String ipString, Boolean tryParse)
    at Membase.MembasePool.InitVBucket(ClusterConfig config, ISaslAuthenticationProvider auth) i n d:\d\repo\EnyimMemcached\Membase\MembasePool.cs:line 206
at Membase.MembasePool.ReconfigurePool(ClusterConfig config) in d:\d\repo\EnyimMemcached\Membase\MembasePool.cs:line 139
2012-01-05 11:49:06 [DEBUG] 6 Membase.MessageStreamListener - Processing message: {"name":"membase","bucketType":"membase","authType":"sasl","saslPassword":"","proxyPort":0,"uri":"/pools/default/buckets/membase","streamingUri":"/pools/default/bucketsStreaming/membase","flushCacheUri":"/pools/default/buckets/membase/controller/doFlush","nodes":[{"replication":1.0,"clusterMembership":"active","status":"healthy","hostname":"WIN-8CSOET2IERN.netgear.com:8091","clusterCompatibility":1,"version":"1.7.1.1","os":"windows","ports":{"proxy":11211,"direct":11210}}],"stats":{"uri":"/pools/default/buckets/membase/stats","directoryURI":"/pools/default/buckets/membase/statsDirectory","nodeStatsListURI":"/pools/default/buckets/membase/nodes"},"nodeLocator":"vbucket","vBucketServerMap":{"hashAlgorithm":"CRC","numReplicas":0,"serverList":["WIN-8CSOET2IERN.netgear.com:11210"],"vBucketMap":[[[LOTS OF ZEROES}}
```

Comment: Couple of questions:  
Which version of the server are you running?  
Which version of the .NET client are you running?  
Could you post a snippet of your calling code?  
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, changing ip address' is an issue with couchbase.

in short:

http://www.couchbase.com/forums/thread/issues-dhcp-development-laptop

```
service_stop.bat
service_unregister.bat
service_register.bat <new-dotted-quad-IP-address>
```